# How to forward a bunch of old Gmail emails?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I tried to create a filter to forward in Gmail and selected the `Also apply filter to 37 matching conversations.`  However, it did not work and the dialog does warn:

> Learn more
>
> Note: old mail will not be forwarded

Clicking [Learn more](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579) shows in part:

> Please note: When you create a filter to forward messages, only new messages will be affected. Any existing messages that the filter applies to will not be forwarded.

Therefore, how can I programmatically cause the 37 emails I'm interested in forwarding to be forwarded without manually sending each one individually in Gmail?

I see this [one solution using Google Docs](http://lifehacker.com/5873647/auto-forward-past-and-future-emails-in-gmail), but it seems pretty complicated to forward my 37 emails, I think manually doing it would be faster than this solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really isn't a simple solution. For 37 messages, I'd almost certainly just do them one at a time. It couldn't possibly take more than a half hour.

One other option might be to use [Google Takeout](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy?pli=1#takeout) to download all the mail messages with a certain label. The messages will be in MBOX format, and many email clients can import that without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [Mail Forwarder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-forwarder/hcfnnagnpmdbaddchgpiojjknjlkeigf?hl=en) add-on for Google Sheets that can also help you forward old emails in Gmail to any other email address.

Comment: I tried using this but couldn't bc your app is not verified with google. >This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Comment: The app has moved to https://emailstudio.pro

Answer (score 0):

If you control the destination account, you can connect both the new account and the Gmail account to a mail client via IMAP. Then drag the 37 messages from the Gmail account to the new account.

Answer (score 0):

Or use https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back , which allows you to transfer emails to/from gmail as a bundle.  I'm not affiliated with this group in any way, but found the software to be friendly and very well built.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, then I have a simple solution for you which allows you to forward 100 message together everyday.
Check out : [Multi Forward For Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-forward-for-gmail/jjmdplljmniahpamcmabdnahmjdlikpm)

Comment: Multi Forward for Gmail has a lot of review that says it dies after forwarding 25 emails. And supposedly it has a 100 email a day limit. So buyer beware, it is free. :)